# With iPad VoiceOver enabled, what causes safari webpage to go to a blank, grey screen?

Tags: javascript, html, css, ipad, voiceover

I'm doing some after-the-fact accessibility testing on a pretty simple web page. It uses Php, basic javascript and css.

What happens is when VoiceOver is turned on, this web page flashes for a second, then goes completely blank.  A solid grey page.

It's clearly not a problem with the screen curtain.  This is solely happening in Safari, and only this web page.  Something must be wrong with my markup, styles or javascript.  I've googled like mad to no avail.

I've begun to pull it apart line-by-line, has anyone come across this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem/solution, as strange as it is.

One line of css broke the entire page.  I had an  present for the sake of accessibility which I didn't want to actually display on the page.  I set it to position:absolute, and top: -999em.

Apparently this breaks a webpage with iPad VoiceOver enabled:

```
top: -999em;
```

However, this is fine (and what I typically do anyway):

```
left: -999em;
```

Comment: This seems like a pretty specific problem, however the correct answer nonetheless.